# adb in parallel execution

Tags: testng, appium

I'm having a problem running adb commands when I run a test in parallel.
The tests execute the adb on the first device it catches, without getting the other device connected.

testng.xml

```
<test name="test">
        <parameter name = "device" value="df74784"></parameter>
        <classes>
        <class 
          name="com.mrl.appium.testcases.SelendroidHomeScreenValidationTest">
        </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

<test name="test1">
        <parameter name = "device" value="qvs33434"></parameter>
        <classes>
        <class 
          name="com.mrl.appium.testcases.SelendroidHomeScreenValidationTest">
        </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

setup class:

```
public class BaseClass

@parameter("device")
@BeforeClass
public void setup(device){
capabilities.setCapability("udid",device)
ADB adb = new ADB(device)
```

ADB class:

```
public class ADB {
 private String ID;

    public ADB(String deviceID) {
        ID = deviceID;
    }
public void forceStopApp(String packageID) {
    command("adb -s " + ID + " shell am force-stop " + packageID);
}
 }
```

Test class:

```
public class test extends BaseClass {

@Test
public void forceClose(){

adb.forceStopApp();

}
```

How can I run the test on both of the devices?

I've been thinking about holding each device in another thread, but dont have a clue how to do that.

Comment: Are you using Appium? If so how many appium servers did you open?

Comment: I'm using appium, I'm creating 2 servers programmatically with the same port and different bootstrap port.

Comment: You can't use the same port, need to use different ports for both devices.